# No ejecuta instalador en Debian 9 x64

Tags: java, debian-9

Tengo un instalador de un libro para linux. Funciona perfectamente en x32, pero en x64 no logro que funcione correctamente. No me funciona ni mal ni bien mejor dicho.
Cuando ejecuto el debug, me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /home/usuario/burlingtonbooks/digitalbook/x64/JRE/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so:
>   libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.awt.DebugHelper.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.awt.Component.(Unknown Source)   at
>   digitalbook.Main.showSplash(Unknown Source)   at
>   digitalbook.Main.main(Unknown Source)

las librerias de java las tengo actualizadas....